# Hash Table in Python

Tags: python, c, dictionary, hashtable, key-value

Currently am using 5 dictionaries in my program where 2 of them have 13 Million key, value pairs. Each Dict is pair where  key is char value of length 1-6, and value is another dict of key, value pair, Now key is of length 1-12 and value is tuple.

This solution in python is working fine but not efficient, on every execution lookup counts approx 0.8 million. when on another script on server written in c which is real-time filtering application used GHashTable and his performance is outstanding.

My Question is if there is any object or implementation which uses GHashTable like hashing function is python for my requirement. Dictionary in python uses hash but why it's that slow in heavy records. Hash used by python dictionary is not efficient compare to GHashTable of c. Is there any better Hash implementation in python available.

python dict works fine in few million records but in heavy load case it failed to respond O(1).

**Does your Python process fit in RAM?**
Yes I have 18GB of Ram and only 8GB is reserved for postgres and other things. while 10GB is available for process.

Comment: To be honest, pure Python might simply not be the best choice for this task, given the size of the data and the performance requirements. (+1)

Comment: You appear to assume the problem is with the hash table, but do you have any evidence for that? Make sure the lookup itself is actually the problem.

Comment: Without a working example that shows your problem, and some profiling you can't tell what is going wrong. AFAIK python's `dict` are fast. there isn't a big performance difference between them and GHashTable, at least for most use-cases.

Comment: I have used cProfile in python while timestamp used in c. python dict works fine in few million records but in heavy load case it failed to respond O(1).

Comment: @NPE Is there any wrapper available for python. like cPickle instead of pickle works faster. because cPickle is c implementation of pickle.

Comment: Does your Python process fit in RAM?

Comment: @JanneKarila Yes I have 18GB of Ram and only 6GB is reserved for postgres and 2GB for other things. while 10GB is available for process.

Comment: Could you show some code that demonstrates the speed of `dict` lookups with simulated data?

Answer (score 0):

When there are hash collisions, the `dict` resolves the collision by using the `__eq__` method, checking for equality by value. This appears to be the reason for your slowdown.

So if for some key a and b, if `hash(a) == hash(b)` then we resolve the collision by checking `my_dict[a]` and  `my_dict[b]`.

For example, by brute force, we find that `hash(2**1000)` equals `hash(16777216)`. Let's test for this,

```
>>> my_dict ={}
>>> my_dict[2**1000] = "One"
>>> my_dict[16777216] = "Two"
>>>
>>>
>>> for k,v in my_dict.items():
...     print(hash(k), v)
... 
16777216 One
16777216 Two
```